# Master Detail in RapidClipse X

Tags: rapidclipse

I see the [Master Detail Feature](https://rapidclipse.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCEN/pages/50758275/Master+Detail) in the documentation of RapidClipse 4, but in the newest version X it seems that feature is missing. Same for the standard buttons in the [Form Wizard](https://www.rapidclipse.com/en/features/html5-gui-builder). I cannot find it in RapidClipse X. Are both features actually only existent in RapidClipse 4 but not in X? If so, are there any tutorials on how to manually implement master detail and form buttons in RapidClipse X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I use simple two grids.
For example, one grid gets filled by the customers and the second grid is connected to the orders.
You can use for the first grid the selectionChangeEvent.
If you select a customer, you can take within the event the selectedCustomer and update the second grid. For this you should implement into the orderDAO something like

```js
select * from orders where customer := selectedCustomer
```

I would also suggest, to search for the RapidClipseX videos in YouTube.
Such things are very well explained by life examples there.

The second part of your question is unclear. All standard ui-objects are also available in RapidClipse X.

Comment: My second question refers to the Form Wizard where the default buttons (New, Reset, Save) cannot be added by the Wizard, as it was the case in Rapidclipse 4. The Form Wizard itself is indeed available in Rapidclipse X also.
The way to add the form buttons manually seems to be similar to what is explained here: https://youtu.be/p3s_xwuG8Wo?t=1869

Comment: I would suggest please download the new version of Rapidclipse X.4 that came out 11th of May, the earlier version was not stable.

Comment: @Marvin: For your second question. The automatic creation of such buttons is not more available.